# does not return response in API call, with http package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I'm using flutter's Http package to connect to an API, but I see that it doesn't return anything, and it doesn't catch the error either.

This is the code.

Just print the first print ()

```
   Future getCountryByName(String name) async {
    try {
      print(name);

      final url = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/colombia';
      final response = await http.get(url);
      print(response);
      return [];
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: it doesnt return anything because you return [ ], als you have to define the type of your future

Answer (score 0):

NetService:

```
class NetService {
  static Future<T> getJson<T>(String url) {
    return http.get(Uri.parse(url))
      .then((response) {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          return jsonDecode(response.body) as T;
        }
        print('Status Code : ${response.statusCode}...');
        return null;
      })
      .catchError((err) => print(err));
  }
}
```

Main:

```
import 'package:_samples2/networking.dart';

class Country {
  static const url = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/colombia';

  static Future<List> getColombiaInfo() async {
    print('Start fetching...');
    return await NetService.getJson<List>(url).whenComplete(() => print('Fetching done!'));
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) async {
  var info = await Country.getColombiaInfo();

  print(info);
}
```

Result:

```
Start fetching...
Fetching done!
[{name: Colombia, topLevelDomain: [.co], alpha2Code: CO, alpha3Code: COL, callingCodes: [57], capital: Bogotá, altSpellings: [CO, Republic of Colombia, República de Colombia], region: Americas, subregion: South America, population: 48759958, latlng: [4.0, -72.0], demonym: Colombian, area: 1141748.0, gini: 55.9, timezones: [UTC-05:00], borders: [BRA, ECU, PAN, PER, VEN], nativeName: Colombia, numericCode: 170, currencies: [{code: COP, name: Colombian peso, symbol: $}], languages: [{iso639_1: es, iso639_2: spa, name: Spanish, nativeName: Español}], translations: {de: Kolumbien, es: Colombia, fr: Colombie, ja: コロンビア, it: Colombia, br: Colômbia, pt: Colômbia, nl: Colombia, hr: Kolumbija, fa: کلمبیا}, flag: https://restcountries.eu/data/col.svg, regionalBlocs: [{acronym: PA, name: Pacific Alliance, otherAcronyms: [], otherNames: [Alianza del Pacífico]}, {acronym: USAN, name: Union of South American Nations, otherAcronyms: [UNASUR, UNASUL, UZAN], otherNames: [Unión de Naciones Suramericanas, União de Nações Sul-Americanas, Unie van Zuid-Amerikaanse Naties, South American Union]}], cioc: COL}]
```

Answer (score 0):

1/ You have to define the type (between < >) for your [Future](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html), Aan object representing a delayed computation, to work properly

> A Future is used to represent a potential value, or error, that will be available at some time in the future. Receivers of a Future can register callbacks that handle the value or error once it is available. For example:

2/ Also carefully read [documentation for http](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data):

> The http.get() method returns a Future that contains a Response

3/ Also read [documentation for FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), as you will probably need it.

## Full working example

You can follow the example of the documentation to properly get your data:

```
class Country {
  final String name;
  final String capital;
  final String region;

  Country({this.name, this.capital, this.region});

  factory Country.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Country(
      name: json['name'],
      capital: json['capital'],
      region: json['region'],
    );
  }

  @override
  String toString() { // nice override to quickly get info about your json
    return 'Country{name: $name, capital: $capital, region: $region)';
  }
}

Future<Country> getCountryByName  (String name) async {
  Country country;
  try {
    final url = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/$name';
    final response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.body);

      country = Country.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)[0]); // the response that you get is an array, you just want to first item.
    }
    else
      print("error: ${response.statusCode}");
  }
  catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
    print(country.toString());
    return country;
}
```

Your Stateful Widget should look like this:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

final String title;

@override
_MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child:  FutureBuilder<Country>(
        future: getCountryByName("colombia"),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Country> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
              snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
          }
          else
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
    })

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And of course don't forget the import:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert'; // for json.decode
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http; // for get request
```

I uploaded the project on [Github](https://github.com/agavrel/Flutter-Get-Request-Example) if you want to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code:

```
import 'dart:convert' as convert; // for jsonDecode
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

 Future getCountryByName(String name) async {
  try {
    print(name);

    final url = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/colombia';
    // http.get returns future of type Future<Response>
    final response = await http.get(url);
    // parse the response and get the resulting json reponse
    var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(jsonResponse);
    return [];
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Reference: [http package usage guide](https://pub.dev/packages/http)